# How to remove duplicates in a column? Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to remove the duplicates on my Names column but I only getting the Unique value. Am I using the wrong command?

`$Data= @()`  <--------- object data source

```
$Data.Name | sort -Unique | ft
```

My output:

```
Name
------
Name1
Name2
Name3
Name12345
Name1
Name2
Name3
```

Desired Output:

```
Name
------
Name1
Name2
Name3
Name12345
```

Comment: `$Data.Name | sort Name -Unique | ft`

Comment: Thank you so much @MathiasR.Jessen! totally works for me now.

Comment: `$Data.Name | Select-Object -Property Name -Unique` would work as well. ;-)